# Vue Web Component with Vite Cors Error on Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cors, web-component, vite

I have build a web component on Vue using Vite and Laravel and it's working fine when i use the npm run dev files but when I use the build js files in my localhost html file It's giving me cors error but when I post the same script on the http://127.0.0.1:8000/ server It's working fine but I can't use in other domains due to cors error Below is my vite.config.js file.

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/js/app.js','resources/js/widget.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                compilerOptions: {
                    isCustomElement: tag => tag.startsWith('widget'),
                },
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
    },
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                entryFileNames: '[name].js',
            }
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'),
        }
    },
});
```

I have tried to add this in my httaccess file to Access-Control-Allow-Origin but still getting same error.

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy 'cross-origin'
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
```